# Python's mysqldb obscure documentation

Tags: python, mysql

There are many escape functions in the Python module mysqldb whose documentation I don't understand, and my efforts at looking them up have revealed nothing.

```
>>> print _mysql.escape.__doc__
escape(obj, dict) -- escape any special characters in object obj
using mapping dict to provide quoting functions for each type.
Returns a SQL literal string.
```

[This documentation page](http://fabrizio.zellini.org/epydoc/MySQLdb/MySQLdb-module.html) says the same thing. But what's supposed to be in that "mapping dict"? I tried a couple of (mostly random) things and only go errors back. What's even more frustrating is that, while the `escape_string()` method works, its documentation string is:

```
>>> print _mysql.escape_string.__doc__
escape_string(s) -- quote any SQL-interpreted characters in string s.

Use connection.escape_string(s), if you use it at all.
_mysql.escape_string(s) cannot handle character sets. You are
probably better off using connection.escape(o) instead, since
it will escape entire sequences as well as strings.
```

So, I am better off using `_mysql.escape()`, am I? Well, uh... okay, but how? What on earth is that "mapping dict"? PHP, in that way at least, was a lot less cryptic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I learned this by looking in /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/connections.py
to see how it called `connection.escape`. A little sniffing around leads to 
`MySQLdb.converters.conversions`. Here is a snippet:

```
{0: <class 'decimal.Decimal'>,
 1: <type 'int'>,
...
 <type 'dict'>: <built-in function escape_dict>,
 <type 'NoneType'>: <function None2NULL at 0xae9717c>,
 <type 'set'>: <function Set2Str at 0xae9709c>,
 <type 'str'>: <function Thing2Literal at 0xae971b4>,
 <type 'tuple'>: <built-in function escape_sequence>,
 <type 'object'>: <function Instance2Str at 0xae971ec>,
 <type 'unicode'>: <function Unicode2Str at 0xae9710c>,
 <type 'array.array'>: <function array2Str at 0xae9725c>,
 <type 'bool'>: <function Bool2Str at 0xae97294>}
```

You can use it like this:

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.converters
import datetime

now=datetime.datetime.now()
connection=MySQLdb.connect(
    host=HOST,user=USER,passwd=PASS,db=MYDB)
print(connection.escape((1,2,now),MySQLdb.converters.conversions))
# ('1', '2', "'2010-07-24 19:33:59'")
```

PS. Regarding Bobby Tables: For normal use of MySQLdb, you don't have to manually escape arguments. Just use parametrized arguments when calling `cursor.execute`, and MySQLdb will automatically quote the arguments for you.

For example:

```
sql='insert into students (name,grade,date) values (%s, %s, %s)'
args=("Robert'); DROP TABLE Students; --",60,now)   # no manual quotation necessary
cursor=connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql,args)
```

Comment: I tried your escape with Little Bobby Tables' name, and it worked. But, knowing that `cursor.execute()` escapes automatically is reassuring too. Is it in that documentation page David Zaslavsky linked to? I didn't see it there... But I may have missed it.

Comment: If you read the XKCD strip, Bobby Tables' actual name is: "Robert'); DROP TABLE Students; --". That's a scary name to put into a database. But a good test case.

Comment: @eje211: Your question regarding where in the documentation does it explain the automatic quotation of parameters is a good one. The best I've been able to find is `The client should not be required to "escape" the value so that it can be used` see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/.

Comment: `MySQLdb.converters.conversion` is explained here as well: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes .

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you're better off using the higher-level interface, MySQLdb. (See the [user's guide](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html))

The `_mysql` functions are really just wrappers around the C API. They're meant to be an implementation detail, the kind of thing that wouldn't even show up in the documentation in PHP. The developers leave them sparsely documented on purpose to discourage people from using them unnecessarily, and also because you can refer to the MySQL [C API documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-escape-string.html) for the equivalent function, which is rather more complete.

Comment: That documentation page is what I looked up first, but those _mysql functions are the only thing that page mentions about escaping data. I remember all too well the terrifying case of Little Bobby Tables: <http://xkcd.com/327/>. What if Little Bobby Tables shows up in MY database? Oh, the terror!

Comment: I know, well the nice thing about MySQLdb is that in normal usage, it handles escaping automatically for you, so there's no way to get an SQL injection when you use the higher-level interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [mysqldb tutorial](http://thepythonguru.com/beginner-guide-to-access-mysql-in-python/). I have used it myself to learn mysqldb