# Getting Results from MySQLdb as text

Tags: python, mysql, type-conversion, mysql-python

Currently each element in the the object obtained after a query is stored as the following:

`((1L, Decimal('30'), Decimal('17')), (2L, Decimal('29'), Decimal('16')))`

I want it in the format:

`(("1","30","17"),("2","29","16"))`

This is because I have to later create a dict with this using `zip()`, then pass it on as a json.

Now of course I can iterate over the entire result, go into each element and `str()` it, but then with huge result sets it would be a very big overhead.

Is there a faster, simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the [`conversions`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.converters-module.html#conversions) mapping by passing `conv` argument to the [`MySQLdb.connect()`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes):

```
import MySQLdb
from MySQLdb.constants import FIELD_TYPE

conv = MySQLdb.converters.conversions.copy()
conv[FIELD_TYPE.DECIMAL] = conv[FIELD_TYPE.NEWDECIMAL] = str

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='...', user='...', passwd='...', db='...', conv=conv)
```

Now, all of the `Decimal` values would be returned as strings.

Also see relevant threads:

- [Python's mysqldb obscure documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327297/pythons-mysqldb-obscure-documentation)
- [Python MySQLdb returns datetime.date and decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483363/python-mysqldb-returns-datetime-time-and-decimal)
- [Python MySQLdb converters isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898516/python-mysqldb-converters-isnt-working)